# Cannot align ScrollView to the top

Tags: ios, swiftui, scrollview

I am having some trouble with `ScrollView`, I have the following code:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    private enum Constants {
        static let cellSize = CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
        static let rowSpacing: CGFloat = 8.0
    }


    @State private var rowCount = 1
    @State private var contentOffset = CGPoint.zero

    private var scrollViewHeight: CGFloat {
        CGFloat(rowCount) * Constants.cellSize.height + (CGFloat(rowCount) - 1.0) * Constants.rowSpacing
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                ScrollView {
                    LazyVStack(spacing: Constants.rowSpacing) {
                        ForEach((0..<rowCount), id: \.self) { _ in
                            LazyHStack {
                                ForEach((1...20), id: \.self) {
                                    Text("Cell \($0)")
                                        .frame(
                                            width: Constants.cellSize.width,
                                            height: Constants.cellSize.height
                                        )
                                        .background(.red)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)
            .frame(maxHeight: scrollViewHeight)
            .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
            .toolbar {
                Button("Add Row") {
                    rowCount += 1
                }
                Button("Remove Row") {
                    rowCount -= 1
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Test")
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason the `ScrollView` content is centered vertically:

[image]

I need the content to align to the top. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: If you want to set the frame at something lower than screen height, add a spacer after to it will not be centered vertically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You used `Vstack` and `Spacer` to align the area of the horizontal scroll view to the top. Please check if the implementation you want is correct.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    private enum Constants {
        static let cellSize = CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
        static let rowSpacing: CGFloat = 8.0
    }


    @State private var rowCount = 1
    @State private var contentOffset = CGPoint.zero

    private var scrollViewHeight: CGFloat {
        CGFloat(rowCount) * Constants.cellSize.height + (CGFloat(rowCount) - 1.0) * Constants.rowSpacing
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                    ScrollView {
                        LazyVStack(spacing: Constants.rowSpacing) {
                            ForEach((0..<rowCount), id: \.self) { _ in
                                LazyHStack {
                                    ForEach((1...20), id: \.self) {
                                        Text("Cell \($0)")
                                            .frame(
                                                width: Constants.cellSize.width,
                                                height: Constants.cellSize.height
                                            )
                                            .background(.red)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
                }
                .background(.cyan)
                .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .bottom)
                .frame(maxHeight: scrollViewHeight)
                .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
                .toolbar {
                    Button("Add Row") {
                        rowCount += 1
                    }
                    Button("Remove Row") {
                        rowCount -= 1
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Test")
                Spacer()
            }

        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove the line where you are setting the frame explicitly.

//.frame(maxHeight: scrollViewHeight)

And check it's working for me.

[image]

Comment: I need to set that height though. I don't want the scroll view to occupy the entire screen height.

Comment: But if you keep adding rows it will go beyond the screen anyway? no?

Comment: What %age of Screen height you want it to max?